# Unable to read same table data from a pdf file spanning across multiple pages using form recognizer client library using C# code

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services, azure-form-recognizer

I am not able to read table data which is spanning across next page. I am using c# code to extract data using FormRecognizerClient
and by using a trained custom model in a console application. Also tried by using StartRecognizeInvoicesFromUriAsync i.e using
analyze invoices of FormRecognizerClient , this is also failed in that scenario mentioned above.

And FormRecognizerClient in C# is also not recognizing headers in a table.
I am using below link for FormRecognizerClient C# library Code,
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/form-recognizer/quickstarts/client-library?tabs=preview%2Cv2-1&pivots=programming-language-csharp#analyze-invoices

Looking for any help.

Below is the image link showing format for pdf :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/mx5NW.png

Answer (score 0):

Form Recognizer does not yet support tables spanning across pages and will extract each table per page. Can you please share a snippet of the table on the second page which is not detected (please anonymize all data and redact all data before sharing)

Comment: snippet is added in the same post

Comment: These should be extracted as line items on all pages in the upcoming release (March 15th) please try this in the invoice model post March 15th here - https://fott-preview.azurewebsites.net/